# UIAlert if function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Im trying to make a calculator and then i have 3 UITextFields.
Its a simply calculation of force.
so you have to put at least 2 Fields something in and the orther will be calculated.
If there is nothing in 2 Fields there must be an UIAlertView.

I already have an UIAlertView and it works. But the Problem is i set the If function that two Fields must have some text in it and when i try it and put just in one Field something the UIAlertView is not displayed, can you helf me?

here is the code im using...

```
- (IBAction)berechnen:(id)sender
{
float kraft = [kraftEingabe.text floatValue];
float masse = [masseEingabe.text floatValue];
float beschleunigung = [beschleunigungEingabe.text floatValue];


if (![masseEingabe.text length] > 0 && ![beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0) {

UIAlertView *nachricht =
[[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Achtung"
message:@"Es müssen 2 Variablen eingegeben werden"
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles:nil];

[nachricht show];

}
if ([masseEingabe.text length] > 0 && [beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0) {

float berechnung = masse * beschleunigung;

[kraftEingabe setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f", berechnung]];
}

if ([kraftEingabe.text length] > 0 && [beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0) {

float berechnung = kraft / beschleunigung;

[masseEingabe setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f", berechnung]];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to display the alertView, if either of the `UITexfield` is empty?
Then `@Oscar` is right you have to use the `||` logical operator if you want to diplay the `UIAlertView` only if one of of the `UITextfield` is empty.

This would display the alert only if both UITextfield are not greater than 0

```
if (![masseEingabe.text length] > 0 && ![beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0)
```

so it should be:

```
if (![masseEingabe.text length] > 0 || ![beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0)
```

the way you set your condition is a little hard to read, in my opinion I prefer:

```
if ([masseEingabe.text length] == 0 || [beschleunigungEingabe.text length] == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

|| means OR, && means AND. If you do arg1 || arg2, if one of them is empty, you will get an alert.

```
if (![masseEingabe.text length] > 0 || ![beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0) {
```

And I can't be bothered to open Xcode and try it myself, but if that doesn't work, try `(!([thingy.text length]>0) || !(samethingagain)`

Comment: Thanks for you Answert but the problem is, I want the && because in both UITextFields there have to be something. So the code shuld be correct with && but why does it not work?
with && there should be something in both UITextFields, but if I try it on the simulator i just have to put something in one of them something in and the alert doesn't display.

Comment: @Joel `![masseEingabe.text length] > 0 && ![beschleunigungEingabe.text length] > 0` means if **both fields are empty** ( if one has something => false), but you need if **some field is empty** ( => both need to have something to be true)